# Polygon scratch file is converting to Multipolygon shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tableau

I digitized somewhat complex (many vertices) boundaries of neighborhoods in QGIS as a Polygon shapefile.  Turns out QGIS thinks they are Multipolygons and Tableau doesn't like them.  They are not multipolygons as per the definition of a multipolygon.

I copied the features into a Polygon scratch layer and confirmed that the wkbType is Polygon.   I then saved the scratch layer using both the Export - Save Features as and the Make Permanent options.  In both cases, it converted the Polygon scratch data to a Multipolygon shapefile.

I have many uses of the data, mostly in QGIS and Python code which don't care, but Tableau is treating the polygons all as one polygon.

Comment: When you export a layer there's usually an option to choose the geometry type. By default that option is set to "auto geometry." Try choosing Polygon when you export. If that doesn't help, try exporting as a different file type (or does Tableau only take shapefile?).

Comment: Thank you @csk.  Turns out that exporting as Shapefile explicitly choosing Polygon as geometry type did not help, exporting as KML also choosing Polygon appears to have set the shape geometry type to a simple polygon.  The real solution with Tableau however was that I needed to add a unique Mark such as the name of the neighborhood so that Tableau would treat each polygon uniquely rather than all as one.  So, more human error that tech issue - documenting in case anyone else encounters this issue.

Comment: Self-answering is encouraged if you find the answer to your own question. Comments can be deleted at any time, while answers are more permanent.